Issue in Accessibility run of UIAlertController
I have a project in which I am using UIAlertController at some places. whenever I am doing accessibility testing the alert is shown on screen, and I get warnings in accessibility inspector for title, message and buttons as in this screenshot.
Below is the code.
 @objc func showCustomAlert() {
    prepareAlert(title: "How would you like to login?", message: "gmail, facebook, apple, twitter, mobile ,github, yahoo")
}

func prepareAlert(title:String, message:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    }))
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}

func showAlert(title:String, message:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    //customize the title
    let titleString = title
    let titleFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        let titleMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .headline)
        let scaledTitleFont = titleMetrics.scaledFont(for: titleFont)
    
    let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: scaledTitleFont, // Custom font and size
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.green            // Custom color
    ]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleString, attributes: titleAttributes)
    alert.setValue(attributedTitle, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    
    //customize the message
    let messageString = message
    let messageFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        let messageMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
        let scaledMessageFont = messageMetrics.scaledFont(for: messageFont)
    let messageAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: scaledMessageFont, // Custom font and size
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
        
    ]
    let attributedMessage = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: messageAttributes)
    alert.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default,handler: { _ in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    }))
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}

I have tried with above two functions with customisation of font and without customisation. The issue still remains.

Please attached the screenshot.

You didn't attach a screenshot.

@Lalitkumar,
Please find the screenshot attched

@Duncan C,
Please see the attached image
